# test lwc zoom in and zoom out oprto

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, slds, slds-grid

whenever user zoom the screen two values gets overlapped with each other.
kindly help me out for this.

without zooming it looks perfectly fine.
kindly help me out for this.

below is my HTML code

```
<div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `slds-truncate` to your wrapper elements to force ellipses to appear when the text is too large to fit its area. It is generally advisable to add a `title` to those elements so the entire text can be seen when hovered over with the mouse.

Example:

```
<div class="slds-truncate" title="Stuart Upifen=htyfudiuigj">
  Stuart Upifen=htyfudiuigj
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Output]

Comment: do we have any  option to truncate if screen size is more then 80%?

Comment: @SryukTim That question doesn't really make sense. What are you trying to accomplish?